# load navigation properties with filter for Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: entity-framework-4, navigation-properties

Few days back I put a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168505/auditing-a-table-with-ef-code-first) regarding mapping two classes `Message` and `MessageStatusHistory` using EF. The mapping is going fine but I am facing some problems with the navigation property `StatusHistory` in class `Message` that relates it to `MessageStatusHistory` objects. I am loading the messages for one user only and want to the statuses pertaining to that user only. Like I would want to show if the user has marked message as read/not-read and when. If I use default loading mechanism like following it loads all the history related to the message irrespective of the user:

```
IDbSet<Message> dbs = _repo.DbSet;
dbs.Include("StatusHistory").Where(x=>x.MessageIdentifier == msgIdentifier);
```

To filter history for one user only I tried following trick:

```
IDbSet<Message> dbs = _repo.DbSet;
var q = from m in dbs.Include("StatusHistory")
        where m.MessageIdentifier == msgIdentifier
        select new Message
        {
            MessageIdentifier = m.MessageIdentifier,
            /*OTHER PROPERTIES*/
            StatusHistory = m.StatusHistory
                             .Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList()
        };

return q.ToList();//THROWING ERROR ON THIS LINE
```

I am getting the error:

```
The entity or complex type 'MyLib.Biz.Message' cannot be constructed in a LINQ 
to Entities query.
```

I have tried by commenting `StatusHistory = m.StatusHistory.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList()` also but it has not helped.

Please help me in getting Messages with filtered StatusHistory.

**EDIT:-** above is resolved with this code:

```
var q = from m in _repository.DBSet.Include("Histories")
        where m.MessageIdentifier == id
        select new {
                     m.Id,/*OTHER PROPERTIES*/
                     Histories = m.Histories.Where(x => 
                                   x.SenderId == userId).ToList()
                   };

var lst = q.ToList();
return lst.Select(m => new Message{
           Id = m.Id, MessageIdentifier = m.MessageIdentifier, 
           MessageText = m.MessageText, Replies = m.Replies, 
           ReplyTo = m.ReplyTo, Histories = m.Histories, SenderId = 
           m.SenderId, SenderName = m.SenderName, CreatedOn = m.CreatedOn
       }).ToList();
```

But if I try to include replies to the message with:

```
from m in _repository.DBSet.Include("Replies").Include("Histories")
```

I am getting error on converting query to List with `q.ToList()` for `Histories = m.Histories.Where(x=> x.SenderId == userId).ToList()`.

Comment: It is not the StatusHistory. See the exception: you can not create entity objects in an entity query. You'll have to create a mirror type or an anonymous type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your EDIT part: You cannot use `ToList()` in a projection, just leave it an `IEnumerable<T>` and convert to a `List<T>` when you construct the `Message`. You also don't need to create two list objects, you can switch from the LINQ to Entities query to LINQ to Objects (the second `Select`) by using `AsEnumerable()`:

```cs
var list = (from m in _repository.DBSet
            where m.MessageIdentifier == id
            select new {
                // ...
                Histories = m.Histories.Where(x => x.SenderId == userId)
            })
            .AsEnumerable() // database query is executed here
            .Select(m => new Message {
                // ...
                Histories = m.Histories.ToList(),
                // ...
            }).ToList();

return list;
```

Be aware that `Include` has no effect when you use a projection with `select`. You need to make the properties that you want to include part of the projection - as you already did with `select new { Histories....`.

Comment: thanks for the help. just a little question: why is `m.Histories.Where(x=>x.SenderId == userId).ToList()` working if I have only `.Include("Histories")` and not when I have `.Include("Replies")` also in the query?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: Are you sure that the second `Include` makes a difference? I honestly would expect that using `ToList()` in the projection never works, no matter if you have an `Include` and how many. It should always throw the infamous "...cannot translate 'ToList' into store expression..." exception.

Comment: Yes you are right. It is throwing exception there also. I mistook another method for this one (with `ToList`).