# Do not allow Expands for specific EntityTypes in Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I'm searching for an elegant way to not allow specific EntityTypes to be [expanded](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_expand) in BreezeJS. We have a (somewhat) public Web Service that we are exposing, and there are some tables that we don't want to be visible to some consumers of that service. Although we can only expose Web API Methods for those specific tables, consumers of the service could still access those tables by expanding from related tables.

**Note:** I've posted an answer to this question, giving a work-around. However, I'm interested if anyone out there knows a more elegant way of skinning this particular cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [UserVoice page for requesting this feature to be formally added to Breeze](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3140624-attributes-on-controller-actions-to-block-the-use-), Ward Bell suggests a decent work-around:

> Meanwhile, in your controller you can examine the query string from the request for presence of $select and $expand and throw an exception if you see it.

I'm guessing this would look something like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Widget> Widgets() {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["$expand"]))
        {
            throw new Exception("Ah ah ah, you didn't say the magic word!");
        }
        return _contextProvider.Context.Widgets;
    }
```

...to block all Expands, or something more specific to block the Expand of Features, itself. This isn't too shabby but not quite "elegant".

(Yes, that is a [Jurassic Park reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfiQYRn7fBg).)

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  It's absolutely correct. I'm really hoping that the UserVoice request mentioned above gets additional votes. I think that this is a very useful feature as well.

Comment: Once you have authentication and authorization in place you can add less restrictive query methods that are only available to authorized users. These action methods are just other resources to query from the client (e.g., `EntityQuery.from('EmployeesForAdmins')`). On the server they're guarded by authorization logic ... and then allowed to do more. This is just another tool on your belt.

Comment: The more elegant solution may be to encapsulate this logic in an attribute that can be placed on the controller (applying to all methods) or on individual methods. Wouldn't be hard. I'll just have to suck it up and do it.